# How do I allow an AWS ECS Task to upload a file to an S3 bucket in the same AWS Account?

Tags: express, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an S3 bucket called **development-test** with zero permissions configured for it. I also have an ECS task setup in Fargate. This task has a task role called **PDFGeneratorTaskS3BucketPutPolicy** with the following trust relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "abc123456abc"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And with the following Policy assigned:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::development-test"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::development-test/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The ECS Task is running two docker containers:

- Nginx Proxy: Location setup for route **/api** to forward POST request to the Express App
- Express App which has one API POST endpoint. This endpoint then generates a PDF and tries to upload it to the **development-test** S3 bucket using the AWS S3 client v3 SDK.

  - This is the code that handles the upload:

```
const uploadToS3 = async (pdf: Buffer, s3Path: string) => {
    const s3Client = new S3Client({});

    // upload the PDF to AWS S3 bucket
    const REGION = process.env.AWS_REGION;
    const BUCKET = process.env.AWS_BUCKET;
    const KEY = s3Path;
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET,
        Key: KEY,
        Body: pdf,
        ContentType: "application/pdf",
        Tagging: "public=true",
    }

    try {

        // upload the PDF to AWS S3 bucket
        console.log('Uploading PDF to S3 Bucket')
        const uploadResponse = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
        console.log('PDF Upload Response => ', uploadResponse)

        const pdfUrl = `https://${BUCKET}.s3.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${KEY}`
        console.log('PDF URL => ', pdfUrl)

        // return the URL
        return pdfUrl;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error in the PDF upload process", err.stack);
        return null
    }
}
```

I use Postman to send a POST request to this endpoint, and the Express app fails to upload the PDF to the S3 bucket:

```
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   Error in the PDF upload process AccessDenied: Access Denied
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at throwDefaultError (/home/app/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at /home/app/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:18:39
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at de_PutObjectCommandError (/home/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:5843:12)
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at async /home/app/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at async /home/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:30:20
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at async /home/app/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at async /home/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/flexibleChecksumsMiddleware.js:63:20
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at async /home/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-endpoint-middleware.js:14:24
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   at async /home/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-middleware.js:9:20
December 07, 2023 at 16:41 (UTC-6:00)   Uploading PDF to S3 Bucket
```

I have been stumped on this since Monday of this week. I cannot get the upload to go through successfully to the S3 bucket.

I have been reading and rereading AWS's documentation:

- [Using IAM roles with Amazon ECS tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/security-iam-roles.html)
- [How can I access other AWS services from my Amazon ECS tasks on Fargate?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-access-aws-services)

I have tried setting up an Access Point for the S3 bucket, along with permissions to allow **PutObject** through the access point. Same error.

I have tried adding permissions to the S3 bucket itself to allow file uploads through an ECS task. Same error.

[image]

This is my NGINX.conf:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
  # NGINX will handle gzip compression of responses from the app server
  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain application/json;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  

  server {
    listen 80;

    # NGINX will reject anything not matching /api
    location /api {
      # Reject requests with unsupported HTTP method
      if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)$) {
        return 405;
      }

      # Only requests matching the expectations will
      # get sent to the application server
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Authorization "";
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

I ran the containers locally with AWS admin credentials and it successfully uploaded:

```
[ ready ] Running on port: 3000
{ key: 'test/hello-world.pdf', html: '<h2>Hello World!</h2>' }
Uploading PDF to S3 Bucket
PDF Upload Response =>  {
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'asdf1234asdf',
    extendedRequestId: '1234asdf1234',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  ETag: '"123asdf1"',
  ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
}
PDF URL =>  https://development-test.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test/hello-world.pdf
```

**Update 12/11**:
I changed the Policy to:

```
"Action": ["s3:*"]
```

and the upload went through successfully.

Comment: Take that JS code and run it locally with admin creds - does that work? Great, that crosses out the code being an issue. Have you validated that `process.env.AWS_BUCKET` is as you expect? `console.log` the PDF URL earlier in the process. Your IAM policy looks fine to me. Are you also sure the task role is set to `PDFGeneratorTaskS3BucketPutPolicy`?

Comment: An ECS task can have two IAM roles attacked to it. It always has to have a Task Execution Role. It can also have an optional Task Role. The optional Task role is the one that would be picked up automatically by the AWS SDK in your code to give it permissions to access the S3 bucket. Please make absolutely sure you are adding these permissions to the ECS Task Role, not the Task Execution Role.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I ran it locally and the PDF successfully uploaded:
`{ key: 'test/hello-world.pdf', html: '<h2>Hello World!</h2>' }
Uploading PDF to S3 Bucket
PDF Upload Response =>  {
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: 'abc123abc123',
    extendedRequestId: 'abc123abc123',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  ETag: '"abc123abc123"',
  ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
}
PDF URL =>  https://officer-metrics-pdf.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test/hello-world.pdf`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I double checked the task definition is using `PDFGeneratorTaskS3BucketPutPolicy` as the Task Role.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I console logged the bucket being passed: `Bucket: 'officer-metrics-pdf'`

Comment: Well that isn't the bucket `development-test` that you're using in your IAM policy - change either/or as they both should match.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I made the switch to the development-test bucket, and I am still getting the same `Access Denied` error.

Comment: Can you try once with action s3:*?  I think some issue with permissions

Comment: @RohitAgarwal I made this change and the upload succeeded. Why would it deny `s3: PutObject` ?

Comment: Ok so now can you please remove s3.* and add s3:PutObjectAcl along with s3:PutObject and try again?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal I added s3:PutObjectAcl and s3:PutObject and it worked! Why would it not work with only s3:PutObject?

Comment: Please read this https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/813